# Global/Local namespace issue while updating Tkinter GUI in Python2.7?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, threadpool, concurrent.futures

**EDIT:**
I have built a User Interface using *Tkinter* in Python 2.7 and I am also receiving data at the socket with *concurrent.futures* module. Now I want GUI to **update** whenever there's a new data at *sock.recv()* but that is not happening, may be because the global *'val1'* is updating in one future thread (that's handling sockets) but not the other thread which is handling the GUI. So the *Listbox* in GUI containing val1 remains static. It is a very long code so instead of putting the whole code here I'm just adding a pseudo-code to clarify the issue.

```
from Tkinter import *
import concurrent.futures
....

class UserInterface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root

        global var1, var2

        # Rest of the code

        self.update()
        root.mainloop() # I have to do this, otherwise the GUI doesn't show


    def update(self):
        try:
            self.var1 = var1
            self.var2 = var2

            # Inserting/displaying the latest values of var1 and var2 in Listbox defined in the constructor
            # Rest of the update function

            self.root.after(5000, update)
        except:
            pass


def conn_handler(conn, addr):
    global val1, val2
    while True:
        buff= conn.recv(2048)
        data= json.loads(buff.strip('x'))    # 'x' is the EOL character
        val1 = ''.join(data[key1]) # not exactly but something like this
        val2 = ''.join(data[key2]) # and so on

def ui_handler():
    root= Tk()
    my_gui = UserInterface(root)
    # I earlier put my_gui.root.mainloop() here but that doesn't help either


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as executor:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
        while True:
            sock.listen(5)
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            future1 = executor.submit(conn_handler, conn, addr)
            future2 = executor.submit(ui_handler)
            concurrent.futures.wait([future1, future2])


if __name__=='__main__':
    val1 = {'key1':value1, 'key2':value2, 'key3':value3, 'key4':value4, 'key5':value5}
    val2 = {'key1':value1, 'key2':value2, 'key3':value3, 'key4':value4}
    main()
```

There is no error in the code when I run it, but it is not doing what I want to be done, that is, **to update the GUI every time there is a new data at the receiving socket**. Is there some fault in my approach/logic ?

**P.S.** I'm quite new to Python and programming in general, so please be kind!

Comment: Also please provide a [mcve] as opposed to '_a pseudo-code to clarify the issue_'.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it is a very long code where I am performing various other things, so I thought it is easier if I explain with a pseudo code.

Comment: While I agree on that, providing a [mcve] is _much_ clearer. And it is way easier than this to understand.

Comment: Well... in that case, please allow me some time so that I come up with a concise code that mimics the basic behaviour of my code & then I shall edit this question with that _Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the issue of local or global namespaces; it may as well be a simple issue of text box or list box not refreshing. I suggest in every update function, you once *delete* the earlier values inside the widget and then *insert* anything new!

In your case, something like this:

```
self.list_box.delete(0, END)
for i in range(len(values)):
    self.list_box.insert(END, values[i])
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! Thanks a ton dude!